# Return the table_name and partition_name whose count have a value of 0

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-partitioning

I'm trying to writing a query that return the table_name and partition_name whose count of that partition have a value of 0.

I've got the below query that return the SELECT COUNT() of the tables and its partition:

```
SELECT 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || TABLE_NAME || ' PARTITION (' || PARTITION_NAME || ');'
FROM user_tab_partitions
ORDER BY table_name;
```

These are some of the SELECT that return:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A5109713 PARTITION (PT5109713_201210);
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A5109713 PARTITION (PT5109713_201104);
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A5109713 PARTITION (PT5109713_201301);
```

The last one it's the only that return data:

```
COUNT(*) |
2430276  |
```

What I need is a query that return the table_name and partition_name of those who has no data. Something like this:

```
TABLE_NAME | PARTITION_NAME
A5109713   | PT5109713_201210
A5109713   | PT5109713_201104
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would a procedure like this:

```
DECLARE
    r INTEGER;
    cur sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
    FOR aPart IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_POSITION) LOOP
        OPEN cur FOR 'SELECT ROWNUM FROM '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' PARTITION ('||aPart.PARTITION_NAME||') WHERE ROWNUM <= 1';
        FETCH cur INTO r;
        IF cur%NOTFOUND THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(aPart.TABLE_NAME||CHR(9)||aPart.PARTITION_NAME);
        end if;
        close cur;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I would not rely on `NUM_ROWS` at view `USER_TAB_PARTITIONS` because the reliability of the information it contains depends on the freshness of your statistics.

I use `SELECT ROWNUM FROM ... WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;` instead of `COUNT(*)` for performance reason. Actually you are not interested in the total number of rows, you just like to know whether they are greater than 0.

In worst case `COUNT(*)` runs a FULL-TABLE Scan which is much slower than reading only the first record.

Comment: It returns me an error message:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at line 6

Comment: Check the SQL string carefully, most likely you forgot a space character.

Answer (score 0):

This method using dynamic SQL is heavy to implement, and slow to execute (since you need to manually count rows in each partition). Also, you now find yourself in need of some additional logic, that will require more PL/SQL code.

System view `user_tab_partitions` has column called `num_rows` that is [documented as](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2098.htm#i1591118): *Number of rows in the partition*. The reliability of the information it contains depends on the freshness of your statistics.

So, if your statistics are up to date, then you can get the information that you are looking for directly from the view:

```
select table_name, partition_name
from user_tab_partitions
where num_rows = 0
order by table_name, partition_name
```

Comment: What is the goal to get these tables/partitions? If you plan to DROP such partitions then I would not rely on `NUM_ROWS` data in user_tab_partitions!